# Regex Match string having exact number of a char

Tags: regex

I Have some strings:

```
1:2:3:4:5  
2:3:4:5  
5:3:2  
6:7:8:9:0
```

How to find strings that have exact numbers of colons?

Example I need to find strings where 4 colons.

Result:

`1:2:3:4:5` and `6:7:8:9:0`

`Edit:`

No matter what text between colons, it may so:

```
qwe:::qwe:
:998:qwe:3ee3:00
```

I have to specify a `number` of colons, but using `regexp_matches`.
It something like filter to search broken strings.

Thanks.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Postgresql using regexp_matches function

Comment: What have you tried? A regular expression to match digit-colon-digit-colon-... should be rather trivial to come up with, no?

Comment: How about `\d+(\:\d+){n}` where n is `number of columns -1`? Thought if you want it as a parameter, it's not going to work.

Comment: I should filter by this condition where to specify the exact number of colons, there may be not only digits.

Comment: A rather fundamental change to the question. Looked like digits, separated by colons, now colons, separated by arbitrary non-colons, even leading and trailing colons to be expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With N being the number you search for:

```
"^([^:]*:){N}[^:]*$"
```

Here is a test:

```
for s in ":::foo:bar" "foo:bar:::" "fo:o:ba::r" ; do echo "$s" | egrep "^([^:]*:){4}[^:]*$" ; done
```

Change 4 to 3 and 5, to see it not matching.

Maybe postgresql needs specific flags or masking for some elements.

```
"^([^:]*:){N}[^:]*$"
"^                $"
# matching the whole String/Line, not just a part
 "([^:]*:){N}[^:]*"
 "(      ){N}[^:]*"
# N repetitions of something, followed by an arbitrary number of non-colons (maybe zero)
 "([^:]*:)"
# non-colons in arbitrary number (including zero), followed by a colon
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the quantifier syntax `{4}`. The quantifier is used to indicate that the preceding capture group needs to occur `n` number of times in order to meet the matching criteria. To find the pattern of five digits separated by semi-colons. something like the following would work.

`((\d\:){4}\d)`

I am assuming you may want any digit or word character but not whitespace or punctuation. In that case use the word character (`\w`).

`((\w)[\:]){4}(\w))`

But depending on what you would like to do with that pattern you may need a different regular expression. If you wanted to capture and replace all the colons while leaving the digits intact your pattern would need to use string replacement or more advanced grouping.

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0):

Any number of any characters, including 4 :

```
((.*:){4}.*)
```